# Read just 6 column from 8 column in readtable instruction

Tags: matlab

I have a .txt file with 8 column . The columns with \t have taken apart. I want read just 6 column with readtable Instruction. please help me. thank you.

The instructions below read all columns table. please correct this instruction for me:

```
Table = readtable('D:\DataIntable.txt','Delimiter','\t','ReadVariableNames',true);
```

Data has 5 millions rows and hence, dropping columns after reading would be pointless time consumption

Comment: Why not just drop the last two columns after reading the whole table?

Comment: Suggestion: Read all data and delete the two last columns.

Comment: Data Have 5 milions rows and this work very hard .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overhead of converting to *.xls is silly. If you read the documentation for [`readtable`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html) you will see that [it supports](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html#input_argument_namevalue_format) `textscan`-style [format specifiers](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#inputarg_formatSpec). This allows you to use `*` to ignore a field.

Using `asdf.txt`:

```
column1 column2 column3
a   b   c
d   e   f
```

And:

```
T = readtable('asdf.txt', 'ReadVariableNames', true, 'Delimiter', '\t', 'Format', '%s%s%*s');
```

We obtain:

```
T = 

    column1    column2
    _______    _______

    'a'        'b'    
    'd'        'e'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can save your data as an .xls file instead of a .txt file, you can use `xlsread` which allows you to specify the range of your data in the call.

```
[data,txt] = xlsread('filename',sheet,xlRange)
```

You would have to know the cell indices of your data in the spreadsheet (i.e. A1:C500 would be a 500x3 matrix of imported data) but it would allow you to specify only importing the desired columns. The `txt` output will import column titles as strings since it appears that you want the names associated with the data as well.

Comment: Execuse me . I did not understand.Your purpose is to take data from a text file into Excel and then MATLAB?This  instruction is for what?

Comment: I was providing you with an alternative to reading data from a text file into MATLAB. If you have the ability to save your data (externally from MATLAB) as an Excel file, then `xlsread` has the functionality you are looking for.

Excel has the ability to load text file tables into its format. You could load your data into Excel, then save the Excel file, then read the data from the new Excel file into MATLAB. _I didn't say that it was the most elegant solution._

Comment: Thank you. another question: how many The maximum file size that can be imported in Excel and Matlab?

Comment: I don't know if there is an actual limit on the file size. If there was a limitation regarding the size of your file, it would most likely come from your computer's memory.

Comment: I want import the text file in Excel. file size is 5 Gig. I give to Excell a samle file with 1 Gig to excell but memory error shown. my system memory is 8 Gig. I do not know what is problem.